# Accessing $(this) inside of a $.post function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, this

I am having a lot of trouble accessing $(this) inside of the function inside the post
all i want to do is remove the object class depending on the response.

```
  $.post("url.php?"+theData, {}, function(response){  etc.....
```

It works fine with a static #ID but i would prefer to manipulate $this

Comment: If you are doing something like `$('element').click(function(){ $.post(){` you'll need to store a reference to $(this) before the post so you can refer to it within the function, like `$('element').cilck(function(){ var me = $(this); $.post("url.php?"+theData, {}, function(resposne({ //me is now $(this); }); });`

Comment: It's probably just a scope issue, but post some more code and maybe it's possible to use a variable instead, but you're code example shows us nothing right now?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
var self = this; 
$.post("url.php?"+theData, {}, function(response){
    $(self).show(); // manipulate this
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a callback from an asynchronous event, so the `this` that points to the element is lost.

You need to preserve a reference to the *outer* `this` (the element). One way is to bind it via an an immediately-executing function:

```
$('#something').on('click', function() {
    $.post('somewhere.php').done((function(el) { return function(response) {
        $(el).removeClass('someClass');
    }; })(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable `this` always point to the current context object.

```
var obj = { // declare object
  a: 2,

  b: function (p) { 
    alert(this.a + p); // here 'this' will point to obj if it was run by 'obj.b();' 
  }
};

obj.b(2); // call it's method
```

Also you may set current 'this':

```
var s = { a: 3 };

var obj = {
  a: 2,

  b: function (p) { 
    alert(this.a + p); // here 'this' will be s 
  }
};

obj.b.call(s, 2);
```

If you use for example 2 functions one (f1) in another (f2) and context of f1 should be available in f2, then the simpliest way is store it in a variable;

```
$(buttonSelector).click(function () {
  var button = $(this);

  $.post(url, function (data) {
    //here button is available
  };
});
```